# SSRS Vertical Text Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an issue displaying vertical text in SSRS. I have developed the report which looks fine when previewing, but when I execute in the .net viewer it bunches the text together.

[image: Differences between SSRS and Report Viewer]

I have set the property CanGrow = true, which I thought might be affecting things. Has anybody come across this before and know how to resolve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same problem with my report server. :( I can seem to figure it out. Did you figure this out ever?